# Want to increment 1 level for every 100 points scored, level counter not working

Tags: javascript

Basically, I want to increment 1 "level" every time 100 "points" are scored. The points work fine, but the levels will not increment for every 100 points. The problem exists in this small bit of code. Any ideas?

```
if (my.collisions()) {
                _total_points += 1;
                my.displayPoints();

                if (total_points >= 100) {
                  _total_levels += 1;
                  my.displayLevels();
                }
            }
```

Here are my displayPoints and displayLevels functions

```
        my.displayPoints = function () {
            gcontext.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
            gcontext.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
            gcontext.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
            gcontext.font = "30px Arial";
            gcontext.fillStyle = "#000000";
            gcontext.fillText("Score: " + _total_points, 10, 50);

        };

        my.displayLevels = function () {
            gcontext.clearRect(100, 100, 200, 100);
            gcontext.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
            gcontext.fillRect(0, 100, 200, 100);
            gcontext.font = "30px Arial";
            gcontext.fillStyle = "#000000";
            gcontext.fillText("Level: " + _total_levels, 10, 150);

        };
```

Comment: Can we see the functions you're calling `displayLevels` and `displayPoints`

Comment: I think you have a typo: `_total_points !== total_points `

Comment: Yes, they've been added to the question

Comment: I see what you're talking about Juan, I'll try it out

Comment: Might be worth noting that you will gain a level for 101, 102, 103 .. etc.
`total_points % 100 == 0` might be better than `total_points >= 100` if you are not subtracting points

Comment: I guess you should reset `total_points` when increasing the level?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if modulus of _total_points and 100 are zero?
I made an example for loop to demonstrate it

```
let _total_points = 0;
let _total_levels = 0;

for (let index = 0; index < 500; index++) {
  _total_points += 1;
  console.log("_total_points " + _total_points);
// if _total_points can be devided by 100, and remainder is zero
  if (_total_points % 100 === 0) {
    _total_levels += 1;

    console.log("_total_levels " + _total_levels);
  }
}
```